# Bianalytic endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been searching for complex analysis problems recently. In [this homework set](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~olga/mat542/hw8_542.pdf)
I found the problem to determine the bianalytic endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$. Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $S=\{0,1,\infty\}$, and $f$ is your bianalytic endomorphism. Now $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at any point of $S$ or it would not be injective. So it has a removable singularity or a pole at each point of $S$. Let's think of a pole as a removable singularity where the function takes the value $\infty$.

Now go ahead and remove those singularities. The value of $f$ at a point of $S$ cannot be a point of $\Bbb C\setminus S$, because then the open mapping theorem would show that the original function cannot be injective. Similarly the value at one point of $S$ cannot equal the value at another point of $S$. So $f$ restricted to $S$ maps $S$ onto itself, and in particular $f$ is an automorphism (or if you insist, bianalytic endomorphism) of the extended plane.

So $f$ is one of the six linear-fractional transformations defining permutations of $S$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so basically at the beginning we are extending $f$ to an automorphism of the Riemann sphere?

Comment: Yes. And we know (?) that the automorphisms of the Riemann sphere are linear-fractional transformations.